# Merging develop into master makes commit moving on top

Tags: git

I'm running in a strange problem that I do not understand.

I have `develop` branch where all the mainstream development goes. Then I have `master` where tags are created.

The situation was clean before but right now, when I merge `develop` into `master` I see a situation like this:

[image]

Before the merge, I see commits in the correct order both with "Ancestor Order" and "Date Order" (using SourceTree, but the same happens with Tower). After the merge, commits and associated tags are moved to the top.

Any idea why it's happening?

Comment: I don't completely follow your diagram and/or the problem.  Why would merging suddenly be behaving differently?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks. I cannot understand why all these commits moves on top. In particular, they seem to move as soon as I do to the merge. What info I could give in order to understand better the problem?

Comment: Are you really merging `develop` into `master` multiple times?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen taken from `git reflog show`
`b8f9139b (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{0}: merge develop: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.`

Comment: Can you show us an example of the "correct order" you see before the merge and an example of what you think it should look like after the merge? I suspect that this will come down to a quirk of your viewer, since it's hard to decide how to display merge parents